# Notification service not working after clicking notification message in status bar

Tags: android, notifications

I referred following links to study the demo example on Notification service in Android : [Sai Geetha Blog](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2009/09/android-developer-tutorial-for.html) and [Vogella Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNotifications/article.html#notificationmanager_example).

Both worked but partially i.e. I've downloaded both projects as it is and executed them. Both has button to initiate the notification. On Button Click notification appears at the top status bar.

Here comes the problem, on click of that notification, neither any message is getting displayed nor intent is getting fired to navigate to new activity.

I'm new to this concept so any help appreciated...

### EDIT

**CreateNotification .class**

```
public class CreateNotification extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public void createNotification(View view) {
        NotificationManager nm= (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        final int UNIQUE_ID = 123458;
        Intent navigationIntent = new Intent();
        navigationIntent.setClass(CreateNotification.this,
                NotificationReceiver.class);

        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, navigationIntent,
                0);
        String body = "New Notification added!!!";
        String title = "Title";
        Notification n = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, body,
                System.currentTimeMillis());
        n.number = 2;
        n.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, body, pi);
        n.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
        nm.notify(UNIQUE_ID, n);
    }
}
```

---

**NotificationReceiver.class**

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.result);
        Log.i("Receiver", "NotificationReceiver");
    }
}
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:onClick="createNotification"
        android:text="Create Notification" >
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

**result.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is the result activity opened from the notification" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this out

```
   public static NotificationManager nm;
public static final int UNIQUE_ID = 123458;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.newone);
    createNotification();

}
public void createNotification() {
    NotificationManager nm= (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    final int UNIQUE_ID = 123458;
    Intent navigationIntent = new Intent();
    navigationIntent.setClass(NEWAct.this,
            TestActivity.class);
    navigationIntent.putExtra("selected_tab", "more");

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, navigationIntent,
            0);
    String body = "New Notification added!!!";
    String title = "Title";
    Notification n = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, body,
            System.currentTimeMillis());
    n.number = 2;
    n.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, body, pi);
    n.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
    nm.notify(UNIQUE_ID, n);
}
```

after your activity launched, you must cancel that notification using the id(UNIQUE_ID)

```
              try {
        nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nm.cancel(UNIQUE_ID);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: oh sorry..response text is the number you want to view notification icon ,that number will displayed on the icon.unique id is a constant id i am edited now

Comment: `navigationIntent.setClass(CurrentClass.this, DestinationClass.class);`   is correct na?

Comment: that notificationreceiver is activity or Broadcastreceiver?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10459/discussion-between-jackson-chengalai-and-gama)